# How to mouse over rows to display full text with VBA or Macros? Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, mouseover, rows

[image: mouse over text]

In Microsoft Access 2007 under (Form View), how do you make text in a table display the entire description when you mouseover one of the rows on the table.  **As shown on the picture above.**

I could not find any information on the internet to accomplish this task with Macros or VBA.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Demonstrated Example. Mouse over to the Linked text.
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/dhtmltooltip.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Shift+F2 for zoom on a field or control.

Comment: Thank you Remou, this works too. The only question remains is how do you hover the rows on the table to display a boxed window with description in it then hover away to make the description box to disappear. When I mean hover I mean mouse over. Thanks.

Comment: In a table, you can't, AFAIK. You have some hope with a form.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this on a datasheet with any of the built-in options.  If, however, you are using a form, you can just put the following code in the Form.Current routine.

```
LongDesc.ControlTipText = LongDesc
```

where LongDesc is the name of the field that you want the tooltip on.

Comment: I have used ControlTipText for MouseMove but I was unable to make the MsgBox go away when I Hover away. This was helpful.

Comment: Sorry, are you using VBA or VB.NET?

Comment: Sorry APrough, I accidently hit Enter when I should have typed Shift+Enter. I could not remove comments. I am using VBA.

Comment: I tried it in MouseMove as well, but I got a really bad flicker on the form.  As I said, this only works on form view, not datasheet view.  If you want it to work on datasheet view, I imagine that you would have to somehow find/write some custom control that would do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help APrough. Mentioning the term "tooltip" allowed me to understand the problem better.